# Angular: Cannot read property 'video_link' in json object

Tags: json, angular, object

So I'm using http.get to get the SpaceX api in JSON format. https://api.spacexdata.com/v2/launches

I wrote a Launch interface to take in all surface level JSON values. I can easily get their values by using:

```
{{ detailedLaunch$.mission_name }}
```

If I want to get a value stored deeper in an object, I would create a statement like:

```
{{ detailedLaunch$.links.video_link }}
```

When I put this in a p or h2 tag it displays the correct link! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dLQ2tZEH6G0 this is exactly what I want!

However, when I try to insert it as an iframe src I get these console errors:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'video_link' of undefined
ERROR Error: unsafe value used in a resource URL context (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss)
```

I created a Links interface as a sub-object of my Launch interface.

```
import { Links } from './Links';

export interface Launch {
  flight_number: number;    
  mission_name?: string;     
  launch_year?: string;      
  launch_date_utc?: string;    
  telemetry?: string;          
  launch_site?: string;        
  launch_success?: boolean;    
  site_name_long?: string;     
  links: Links;                            
  details?: string;
```

and

```
export interface Links {
  mission_patch: string;
  mission_patch_small: string;
  article_link: string;
  wikipedia: string;
  video_link: string;
}
```

This is the exact line throwing the error:

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="{{ detailedLaunch$.links.video_link }}">
        </iframe>
```

Comment: could you add the code where you assign the value to the variable ?

Answer (score 1):

Making an http request is asynchronous operation so before the requrst you object is an empty object

an example

```
let o = {} ;
o.address ; // undefinde 
o.address.street ; // Cannot read property 'street' of undefined
```

a short solution is to hide the iframe elemnt while requesting json object

```
<iframe *ngIf="detailedLaunch$.links" width="420" height="315" 
        src="{{ detailedLaunch$.links.video_link }}">
</iframe>
```

in this case if detailedLaunch$.links has a value will render the iframe